# What is the best way to answer this scheduling algorithm scenario?

Tags: algorithm, logic

This is a question I got in an interview. It is little hard to explain, please bear with me.

Imagine a Railway Ticketing Counter.

- Initially there are 3 counters.
- There is a security guard who keeps a check on the people so that no one breaks the line.
- Each counter has 2 people waiting in line. The people waiting in line came in as per the alphabetical order.
- A new 4th counter is being opened. And there are two new persons G and H about to join the line.

You are the security guard, now you get to choose who can be processed at the new counter.

[image]

Counters are marked 1, 2, 3 and 4 (blue boxes). People waiting in line are marked A, B, C and so on. Here A came first, followed by B and then C etc.

I was asked to give the answer and the logic behind the answer. 
The interviewer kept on asking more questions on my answers.

For example - when I said,

- I will ask D and E to move to the 4th counter;
- G will stand behind A and H will stand behind B

The interviewer argued saying how is it that E and G get the same preference (priority).

After few minutes of such arguments, I told like this seems to be a simple scheduling problem which can easily be solved if there was a common queue and the security guard sends the next person on the queue to a vacant counter following FCFS.

[image]

However, the interviewer was not impressed.

Is there a different approach which I missed? What is the right way to answer such questions?

PS: I didn't get through this round :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given my background in the topic and more years in the industry than I'll admit here ... :-) ... I have a hypothesis as to why you didn't make the next round: this is not so much a program design question as a behaviour question.

This class of interview question is often not about the solution, but about your problem-solving *approach*.  I (interviewer) gave you a problem with several open possibilities.  First of all, this is "obviously" a metaphor for an OS multi-processing situation.  I want an ideal candidate to

1. Question the ticket-counter paradigm's applicability to the OS situation: what assumptions exist in the real world that don't apply to a process queue?
2. Determine the rubric for evaluating a solution.
3. Ask for more information on permitted operations.
4. Ask for a distribution of service times, arrival times, etc. to demonstrate knowledge of the scheduling paradigm.
5. Inquire about costs & trade-offs.

Armed with a better description of the problem, *now* I want you to work through a solution, consistently engaging your customer (me) in the general approach and the specifics.  This is a critical part of the Agile approach, for instance.  Also, I want to see how you explain things I don't understand.

Note that item #2 is *very* important: if your true customer for this is a corrupt security guard retiring at the end of the shift, then the correct solution might be to hold a bribery bidding war for access to the open counter.

Here's *your* homework for the next interview: what assumptions are necessary to make your given solution a good one?  How can you validate those assumptions with your customer?

My immediate questions include the ones above, and ...

- What defines a good solution?  best solution?  unacceptable?
- What's the cost of moving a person from where they are to another place?

  - Can I take someone out of a window line and back into the queue?
  - Can I change order in the queue (i.e. common usage of "queue" rather than the canonical data structure)?
  - Can I switch someone directly from one window line to another?
- Do I *have* to serve every customer?
- Is that the entire queue, or is this a continuous process?

This is where my typing caught up with my thought processes, a fair point to stop.

Answer (score 3):

If people are coming in alphabetical order AND each one get served in roughly the same time, then IMO the most "fair" solution would be to mode `D` to a new counter, move `E` after `A`, move `F` after `B` then let `G` and `H` to move in, i.e.:

```
1  2  3  4      1  2  3  4
----------      ----------
A  B  C     >>  A  B  C  D
D  E  F         E  F  G  H
```

The logic is that since `A` came first, he should be served first, so `E` will get to the counter faster standing after `A` rather than standing after `B`.

**Update from the comments:**
To avoid many movements:

```
1  2  3  4      1  2  3  4      1  2  3  4
----------      ----------      ----------
A  B  C     >>  A  B  C  D  >>  A  B  C  D
D  E  F            E  F         G  E  F  H
                G        H
```

For four people in line:

```
1  2  3  4      1  2  3  4      1  2  3  4
----------      ----------      ----------
A  B  C         A  B  C  D      A  B  C  D
D  E  F     >>     E  F  H  >>  G  E  F  H
G  H  I         G     I  L      J  K  I  L
J  K  L         J  K            M  N  O  P
                M  N  O  P
```

Comment: I kind of gave this solution as well. Then the interviewer asked me what if there were 4 persons already in the q instead of 2. Then making those many movements is not optimal. am I correct?

Comment: well, if we would like to avoid many movements, something in between could be used, i.e.: `D` move to 4, `G` to 1 and `H` to 4. For 4 persons in the queue, we could move just one person per row, i.e. before: `1: {A, D, G, J} 2: {B, E, H, K} 3: {C, F, I, L}` after: `1: {A, G, J, M} 2: {B, E, K, N} 3: {C, F, I, O} 4: {D, H, L, P}`

Comment: seems you have cracked this. please wait for some more time. If there is no better answer I will mark yours.

Comment: In the updated answer if A finishes first, then `G` gets priority over `E` and `F`? I understand that the reason is that we do not want many movements.

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan sure, simplicity comes with a cost of not quite fair scheduling, but close enough. Overall, IMO your second answer (i.e. change the scheduling to FCFS) is the best and will work even when the time of service is different. So, not sure what exactly the interviewer wanted to hear, frankly...

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be

D->4, E->1, F->2, G->3, H->4

on the premise that each person will take the same amount of time at the counter. This way everyone will be processed in the right order.

If each person will take a different unknown time at the counter then a queue is the only valid solution (besides switching the lines each time someone got processed which is effectively the same).

Comment: I guess you meant G->3 H->4

Comment: why would we need a priority queue? a normal queue will not suffice?